# list item selection not working

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement a list where the user can select an element. I can select items but the "active" class is not removed from the previous ones. If I click in all of them, then all will be selected.
I am developing using twitter bootstrap and angular

```
<ul class="list-group" id="list-opponents">
  <li *ngFor="let opponent of model.availableOpponents; let first = first" [class.active]="first" id="{{ opponent.id }}" data-toggle="list" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">                
    <span class="mr-3">{{ opponent.name }}</span>
    <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="{{opponent.photoUrl}}" />
  </li>          
</ul>
```

the produced html is the following:

```
<ul _ngcontent-c1="" class="list-group" id="list-opponents">
  <!--bindings={ "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object"}-->
  <li _ngcontent-c1="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center active" data-toggle="list" id="1">                
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="mr-3">Me</span>
    <img _ngcontent-c1="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="../../../assets/ana.JPG">
  </li>
  <li _ngcontent-c1="" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" data-toggle="list" id="2">                
    <span _ngcontent-c1="" class="mr-3">You</span>
    <img _ngcontent-c1="" class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="../../../assets/tininha.JPG">
  </li>          
</ul>
```

UPDATE: you can find a jsfidle here: https://jsfiddle.net/Bonomi/Lkz161er/7/

Comment: can you show us your typescript code ?

Comment: The list want to become active if it is selected right. Initially first list should be selected that are you saying right

Comment: the typescript is working well as you can see in the html output. The "Active" class should be manipulated my the bootstrap.js and it keeps adding the class to the elements I click, but not removing it from the previous

Comment: @Bonomi you didn't show the part that allow you to *select items*

Comment: @KelvinLai, I am not doing any action with it, the active class is added and removed by twitter bootstrap, see here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#javascript-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I figured out what the problem is. I can't use the ul li elements, I solved the problem using div and a:

```
<div class="list-group" id="list-opponents">
    <a *ngFor="let opponent of model.availableOpponents; let first = first" [class.active]="first" id="{{ opponent.id }}" data-toggle="list" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
      <span class="mr-3">{{ opponent.name }}</span>
      <img class="figure-img img-fluid rounded" src="{{opponent.photoUrl}}" />
    </a>          
</div>
```

It works now.